# Uniswap Router initialization in Ethereum mainnet versus BSC

Tags: ether, binance, binance-smart-chain

I analyzed the source code contracts of several tokens, and I noticed a line of code that differs between two similar ones that I am trying to make sense of.  Specifically, I would appreciate your guidance on what must go in the contract part within the parentheses:

- Token 1 Code (based on binance smart chain)

```
IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);
```

- Token 2 Code (based on ethereum)-

```
IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
```

Does the difference between the two of these have to do with binance versus ethereum? Does it have to do with something else?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's the difference of Binance vs Ethereum. Different chains might have different addresses for different contracts.

On Ethereum, [Uniswap's router](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02) is deployed on the second address you mentioned.

On BSC, Uniswap is not deployed, but the popular exchange there is PancakeSwap that cloned Uniswap. If we go to [PancakeSwap's documents](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/router-v2), we see that the address is different from the address in your token contract. Let's try to find out what your address is.

If we enter your BSC address in BSCscan, we'll see the contract is PancakeRouter and has been deployed by Pancakeswap's Deployer. So it does belong to PancakeSwap.

We do not see it on the documents because it is RouterV1 (which is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore) and not RouterV2.